# "Белая, тщательно отглаженная скатерть", но "чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна". Как объяснить запятую в первом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, определения, однородные-неоднородные-определения

*На белой, тщательно отглаженной скатерти появились медвежье мясо, вяленая сохатина* (Аж.)

Но: *чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна.*

Во втором примере нет запятой, так как определения - неоднородные, то есть первое определение относится к сочетанию второго определения с существительным;

В первом предложении есть запятая, но разве это однородные определения?

**Как определить, когда ставить запятую, а когда нет, если первое определение выражено прилагательным, а второе - причастным оборотом?**

(Приведенные примеры - из Розенталя.)

У Лопатина же: § 38. Определения-прилагательные могут сочетаться с причастными оборотами. Постановка запятой зависит в этом случае от местоположения причастного оборота, который выступает то в качестве однородного с определением-прилагательным члена предложения, то — неоднородного.

Если причастный оборот стоит после определения-прилагательного и перед определяемым словом (т. е. разрывает непосредственную связь прилагательного и существительного), то между определениями ставится запятая: *Даже старые, серыми лишаями покрытые ветви деревьев зашептали о прошлых днях* (М. Г.);

Если причастный оборот стоит перед определением-прилагательным и относится к следующему затем сочетанию определения-прилагательного и определяемого слова, то запятая между ними не ставится: *Каждый раз появлялась и снова тонула в кромешном мраке припавшая к широким балкам степная станица* (Пауст.);

И нет примеров без запятой между определением, выраженным прилагательным, и определением, выраженным причастным оборотом.

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь уже всё придумал, причём и [пояснить не поленился](http://m.tululu.org/bread_81315_28.xhtml):

> чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна; заячий наполовину потёртый
>   воротник; большой собранный автором материал и т. п. — ***первое
>   определение относится к сочетанию второго определения с
>   существительным.***

Думаю, Вы хотели спросить именно про отсутствующую запятую? Потому что наличествующая не вызывает сомнений в своей законности.

---

Запятая ставится, если [(пункт 7)](http://m.tululu.org/bread_81315_27.xhtml):

> за одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным
>   оборотом: малоизвестные, расположенные на отшибе курганы; древняя,
>   почерневшая от времени деревянная статуэтка; небольшое, устланное
>   коврами возвышение; чёрные, гладко причёсанные волосы; худое,
>   изборождённое глубокими морщинами лицо; пустое, запорошенное снегом
>   поле; ранняя, чуть заигравшая зорька; твёрдый, плохо выбритый
>   подбородок (ср. при другом порядке слов: плохо выбритый твёрдый
>   подбородок).